# Google Play Alpha Upload is hanging on Processing state

Tags: android, google-play

I've uploaded an APK into the Alpha tab onto the Google Play Console. It sat in the Processing state for over a day.

I canceled it after 24 hours and reuploaded it. It's been almost a week and it's still in the Processing state.

Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing the infinite Processing state on the Google Dev Console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to contact Google Play support through the [publishing contact form](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/publishing).

The upload can hang from time to time. Usually the APK will complete its Processing State after a few days.